# Change the language of the CiviVolunteer component

Tags: civivolunteer, language

I have a clean installation of CiviCRM on Wordpress on a Bitnami AWS installation. Later I was able to change the language to Spanish MX of all CiviCRM but it has not changed the language of the CiviVolunteer component.

I installed the [l10n and SQL Translation files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/4.4.3/civicrm-4.4.3-l10n.tar.gz/download) but this doesn't work for CiviVolunteer. How can **I change the language of this component to Spanish MX**?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code (e.g. the [settings part](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/master/settings/volunteer.setting.php)), CiviVolunteer is not translated, nor easily translatable (the text is hard coded).

In order to make it translatable, some programmer needs to add the translation strings.

Comment: or could you just fork CiviVolunteer and manually overwrite the text 'if' this is just to 'convert' it to one other language

Answer (score 1):

There might not be a translation for it, but check out [l10nupdate](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update) which helps you download translations for extensions.

By the way the core translations you linked to in your question are very old. The newer ones are at https://civicrm.org/download - in the dropdown is a choice for the localization files.

Comment: @Demérito thanks for your info but however this did not work for me